# Express checking if email exists. Is it properly done?

Tags: express

I need to check if the email exists in database. If not it would be possible to add new User. is it done correctly? It's controller folder.

```
const addUser = (req, res) => {
    const{email, password, firstName, lastName, sex, rating, telephone, role, lastSeen} = req.body;
    let errors = [];
     User.findOne({email: email}, async(err, user) => {
        console.log(user);
        if(!user){
            try{
                const newUser = new User({email, password, firstName, lastName, sex, rating, telephone, role, lastSeen});
                await newUser.save();
                res.status(200).send("Successfull");
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error.message);
            }   
        }else{
            res.send("User exists")
        }
    })
```

}

Comment: Is this working or not??

Comment: Yes, it's working, but i don't know if await methods are done properly

Comment: [please read this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/write-operations/upsert/#performing-an-upsert)

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to use async await:

```
const addUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password, firstName, lastName, sex, rating, telephone, role, lastSeen } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'User already exists' });
    }

    const result = await User.create({
      email, password, firstName, lastName, sex, rating, telephone, role, lastSeen
    });

    res.status(201).json({ message: 'User created', user: result });

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! If I understand it correctly, I use async flag to say that this function will be asynchronous and then await to wait till indyvidual functions will be done?